# Judenstern (Jeckische Shabbat lamp)

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, candle-lighting, yekke

Historically, German Jews used a lamp like the one shown below for neirot Shabbat. Does anyone still make it? If so, where could it be found?

[image: Judenstern]

Answer (score 2):

I have one original for sale. Can be contacted at +1-650-417-8552

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Hermann. Unfortunately, while this answers the question, it goes against our format. I hope you enjoy our community regardless and enjoy our other questions tagged [yekke]